# Is it possible to "preload" all thumbs.db files in a directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-media-center, thumbnails

Kind of a weird question I guess :p Was just curious to if there is a way I can preload all thumbs.db files in directory (and its sub-directories) so that when I visit those folders later in explorer or media center, the thumbnails are already loaded.

Not so important for images, but would be handy to do once in a while for folders with lots of video files that seldom changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can "force" to create all the needed Thumbs.db if you do a search of all image files in your disk, and then set the view to "Thumbnails".

Comment: Oh, nice trick. will have to try that out, hehe. Thanks! Will accept this as answer, since there haven't really been any other suggestions. and I kind of doubt there are any...

Comment: I’m pretty sure you still have to scroll through the whole list.

Comment: What "thumbnails" option are you refrencing here? Is this a pre-Windows 10 thing? because I am not seeing it.

Comment: Well, it was 2009 so yes, very pre-Windows 10! In W10 anything bigger than "small icons" should enable the thumbnails view.

Answer (score 2):

Thumbs.db *is* a caching mechanism.  It stores the thumbnails so the system doesn't have to scan every file in the folder to get it's thumbnail.  There's no way to cache it beyond that.

E: even though you're seeing the thumbs.db files, I would double check that the system is actually using them (and updating/generating new ones) by making sure Folder Options->View->"Do not cache thumbnails" is **unchecked**.  Beyond that, I don't think you've got any options.

Comment: Well, I know they are the caching mechanism. Was just wondering if it was a way of pre-hitting all the files in all the folders so that everything was already cached when I started to browse through them =)

Comment: The "Do not cache thumbnails" has been deprecated and is no longer available in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning Windows XP: Doing a SEARCH for images (*.jpg, *.bmp, ...) and switching to thumbnail-view does only TEMPORARILY generate those thumbnails: NO thumbs.db file(s) get generated and stored!

But recently I found out a special trick that can be used for an automatization procedure (e.g. command batch-file): If you first copy a (wrong) dummy thumbs.db-file into a folder and open that directory with windows explorer in thumbnail-view, you now DON´T HAVE TO SCROLL through the directory any more to get all thumbs generated!

Certainly it will take some time, especially in huge image-folders, until your (slow) single-core PC finishes the generation of the thumbs.db file. When it´s generated, or doesn´t grow in size any more, you can recursively traverse to the next directory in your batch-file.

Answer (score 2):

I made a free open-source tool for this task: [WinThumbsPreloader](https://github.com/bruhov/WinThumbsPreloader/).

It allows you to preload thumbnails for the directory and, optionally, its subdirectories from the context menu of the directory.