# NAS: pre-generating thumbnails for multiple clients

Tags: nas, photos, thumbnails, thumbs.db

I have a simple setup: Linux server at home with a huge drive; that drive has a photo library (hundreds of folders, hundreds of gigabytes). The drive is shared with multiple Windows and Mac clients using Samba.

Question: is there a utility I can run to pre-generate all thumbnails inside a folder, so that my clients would be able to navigate the library faster?

Thank you.

Comment: One promising direction, but only for Mac: http://www.phillips321.co.uk/2013/08/14/synothumb-py-only-does-pics-but-is-for-os-x/

Comment: One other lead: http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=34112.0

Comment: See the Edit to my answer.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I don't see your answer, looks like it disappeared

Comment: [This was asked a while back.](http://superuser.com/questions/17364/is-it-possible-to-preload-all-thumbs-db-files-in-a-directory) There still seems to be no way to do it.

Comment: `I don't see your answer, looks like it disappeared` When he figured out what you were asking, he updated his answer to say that he can’t find any way to do it, then deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Mac use different cache formats to store thumbnails.

`Thumbs.db` is deprecated for the Windows platform, since Vista, they've been stored in a proprietary database located in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` on each individual computer.

For Mac OSX and later, the thumbnail cache is stored in `~Library/caches/` on each individual computer.

So, as the "disappeared" answer earlier started, there is no way to pre-generate thumbnails for Windows Explorer or Mac Finder.  What one **could** do, is pre-generate folders with thumbnail'd images. I do this for my personal photo library, I have a cron script to run imagemagick over new images to generate a 100x100 thumbnail.