# Creating preview thumbs for a Windows directory with images

Tags: windows, images

I have a directory with ~100k small images inside it (training images for machine learning). I'd like to be able to quickly scan the directory for errors, but preview thumbs are only created when the i view the area of the folder the filename appears which means I have to scroll down the entire directory to create the thumbs, so then I can quickly scan them.

Is there a way to force windows to create thumbs for an entire directory?

Comment: you should distribute the images into subfolders. Having a large number of files in a folder is not a good idea

Comment: [How to automatically create Windows thumbnails recursively?](https://superuser.com/q/860471/241386)